# React V16.7 TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
  import React, { useContext } from 'react';
  useContext is undefined.
```

error details:

```
  Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
```

error when processing

```
   const context = useContext(UserContext);
```

Current react versions:

```
   "react": "^16.7",
  "react-dom": "^16.7",
```

Comment: Hooks are available only in the alpha version currently

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To fix the issue downgrade react and react-dom to 16.7.0-alpha.2 as hooks are not available in v16.7

```
    "react": "16.7.0-alpha.2",
    "react-dom": "16.7.0-alpha.2"
```

Comment: This is not working for me. Is there any other possible solution?

Comment: found this solution `"react": "next",
"react-dom": "next"`